# TeamCity - Reporting on success of multiple projects configurations in one place

Tags: teamcity

We currently have TeamCity setup so we have a project per component (Website, APIs, Mobile App, etc). Each project contains a Functional Tests configuration.

All of these components are dependent on the same database, which has migrations applied to it. The migrations are applied before the functional tests run, so problematic migrations cause builds to fail. However to discover which Functional tests fail as a result of a migration we have to manually view each one (we currently have 15+ components, and associated TC projects, so it's not ideal).

In order to be able to see the results of all Functional Test configurations in one place, is it possible to aggregate the results of all the Functional Test configurations into a new project WITHOUT creating templates of the current functional test configurations and setting these up in the new project?

Comment: Is it possible to remove dependency on one DB? Also you probably could setup dependency between TC builds so if one fails other won't start. but it will slow down all process.

Comment: Although the components aren't dependant on the same physical database in the context of TeamCity, they are all dependent on the same DB in production. There's activity to remove this dependency but that won't happen for a while. I might have a solution using snapshot dependencies.